# EF ValidationContext: How to know if entity is being created or updated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

Making a custom validation for an entity in MVC I implemented the `IValidatableObject` interface.

Now, in the validation code I would like to do something if the entity is being Created and something different if it is being updated. Take the following code as an example of what I want:

```
public partial class ActividadProyecto : IValidatableObject
    {

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (IsBeingCreated)
            {
                // Do stuff
            }
            else if(IsBeingUpdated)
            {
                // Do other stuff
            }
        }
}
```

Is it possible somehow? I have searched a lot and haven't got any close to this. The only solution I found was to make a ViewModel for Create process and anotherone for Update process and then make independent validators for both of them: This is just insanely wrong and ugly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: a quick help, if you are using int/long as primary key of your tables, then if the Id>0 => update else its insert

Comment: Thanks... sadly using GUID for client requirements.

Comment: @HadiHassan I ended up using your suggestion using GUID and validating against `Guid.Empty` to check if the entity was being created or updated. I tried a lot of alternatives and couldn't achieve what I wanted. This solution is simple and though I think it can be done better, at least for a while it will keep happy. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By overriding the `ValidateEntity()` method in your `DbContext`, you can pass down the required information to your entity's `Validate()` method via the `validationContext.Items` dictionary object.

DbContext:

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    // other code

    protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
    {
        items["is_data_layer"] = true;
        items["is_insert"] = this.Entry(entityEntry.Entity).State == EntityState.Added;
        return base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);
    }
}
```

Usage from your entity:

```
public partial class ActividadProyecto : IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        object dummy;

        // skip logic if "Validate" is not called from EF...
        if (validationContext.Items.TryGetValue("is_data_layer", out dummy))
        {
            if ((bool)validationContext.Items["is_insert"]) // insert mode
            {
                // Do stuff
            }
            else // update mode
            {
                // Do other stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

I'll admit that I answered from a purely EF (data layer) point of view.  I'm no ASP.NET MVC expert. But as `mo.esmp` points out, it makes sense that if you're also using the EF entity as your "view model", then the MVC framework will *also* invoke the `Validate()` method to validate the entity in the view layer. And only *after* will EF invoke the `Validate` method as well. So that would explain why your entity's `Validate` method gets called *before* the context's `ValidateEntity` method.

So, the question becomes: Which validation are you interested in for your added logic?  Do you want to add logic to the "view layer" validation? Or do you want to apply your logic during the "data layer" (EF) validation?

I don't have enough details to answer that for you.  But in case you only need to add your logic during the "data layer" (EF) validation phase, then I've adjusted my sample code above to skip the logic if the validation is not being invoked by EF. You can try that out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I faced one problem though, for some reason the `Validate` method is called before the DbContext `ValidateEntity` :-/ Any ideas?

Comment: `mo.esmp`'s comment provides a reasonable explanation for what you observed. I adjusted my answer to (hopefully) work around it. But it depends on whether you are trying to add your logic during the "view layer" validation phase, or the "data layer" (EF) validation phase. I hope it helps you.

Comment: This can be done like you said and is a great solution but it adds the complexity of capturing the `DbValidationError` exception and send the error to the view in MVC so I just chose to drop this option. Thanks anyway! Will mark it as answer because this really works if you want to go deeper and fix the other problems to make it work in MVC.

Answer (score 1):

When you post the Form to the server, ASP.NET MVC model binder tries to bind the `Form` to `ActividadProyecto` entity and `IValidatableObject.Validate` method will be executed to validate your model but when you try to save the entity, EF `ValidateEntity` method will be executed. so in `IValidatableObject.Validate` method you cannot determine weather entity was created or updated because it occurs before EF `ValidateEntity` method.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifycation of the behavior of the validation. Just wanted to clarify that as @sstan pointed out, it can be done with some additional code.